# Click event if element is checked and reload page

Tags: if-statement, click, reload, checked

I would like a `reload.location` click-event only if a checkbox is checked. To me this seems to be basic conditions, but it's not working. Perhaps a different approach is needed? What I figured out, is when the checkbox is ticked, there is no html change in the `<input type="checkbox">` element. Maybe this is the reason or is the combination of these conditions not possible? The else statement is a call back to the previous UI page. In below attempt, it's skipping the if-statement.

My attempt:

```
$(document.body).on("click", "#button", function(){
        if (document.getElementById('checkbox').checked) {

                location.reload(true);

        } else {

        return_to_page( this.dataset.return )

        }
    });
```

---

Above is working, however it's ignored due to the missing preventDefault:

```
$(document.body).on("click", "#button", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    //etc

});
```

Answer (score 1):

`checked` is not a property of a jQuery object. You can use `prop()` to get the property instead:

```
$('#button').click( function() {
  if ($('#checkbox').prop('checked')) {
    location.reload(true);
  }

  // alternative #1 - use the 'checked' property of the Element in the jQuery object:
  if ($('#checkbox')[0].checked) {
    location.reload(true);
  }

  // alternative #2 - use the 'checked' property of the Element outside of jQuery:
  if (document.getElementById('checkbox').checked) {
    location.reload(true);
  }
});
```

Here's a working example:

```js
$('#button').click(function() {
  if ($('#checkbox').prop('checked')) {
    // location.reload(true);
    console.log('Reload would happen now...');
  } else {
    console.log('Staying on the current page');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" /> 
  Reload?
</label>
<button id="button">Go</button>
```

Comment: I have tried these methods, but it keeps skipping the if-statement. I have updated my query with the complete statement.

Comment: I added an example to show this logic working. If you have issues I would suggest checking the console for errors.

Comment: Solution for me is to put a function(e){ e.preventDefault();

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#button').click( function() {
    if( $("input[id='checkbox']:checked") ) {
        location.reload(true);
    }
});
```

alternative

```
$('#button').click( function() {
    if( $('#checkbox').is(':checked') ) {
        location.reload(true);
    }
});
```

All in a one plate methods:

```
$('#checkbox').is(":checked")

$('#checkbox').prop('checked')

$('#checkbox')[0].checked

$('#checkbox').get(0).checked
```